# execute Worksheet_Change when cell changed by a macro

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have edited this question from initial posting since I realized that no macro will activate the Worksheet_change function.

I am using a UserForm to create a macro to edit a cell. Then I want the Worksheet to take the value from one cell and create values in other cells. This works manually, but not in via macro!

From the UserForm:

```
Sub WriteOperatingFunds(dates, description, money)
  Dim ws2 As Worksheet
  Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OperatingFunds")

  'find first empty row in database
  irow = ws2.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

  ws2.Cells(irow, 1).value = dates
  ws2.Cells(irow, 2).value = description
  ws2.Cells(irow, 3).value = money
End Sub
```

And from the worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim change As String
  Dim chngRow As Long
  Dim IncRow As Long
  Dim ExpRow As Long
  Dim TotRow As Long
  Dim Income As Long
  Dim Expense As Long
  Dim Total As Long

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OperatingFunds")

  TotRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row 'finds bottom of 'Total' Column
  'looks for target in range
  If Not Application.Intersect(Target, ws.Range("C3", ws.Cells(TotRow + 1,        4))) Is Nothing Then
    change = Target.Address(False, False)
    chngRow = ws.Range(change).Row

    'Get the last rows of range columns
    IncRow = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ExpRow = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.EnableEvents = False 'to prevent endless loop & does not record changes by macro
    'if Total column is empty
    If ws.Cells(chngRow, 5) = "" Then
        Income = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range("C3", ws.Cells(TotRow + 1, 3)))
        Expense = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range("D3", ws.Cells(TotRow + 1, 4)))
        Total = Income + Expense
        ws.Cells(chngRow, 5) = Total
    'if total column is not empty (i.e. needs to be rewritten)
    ElseIf ws.Cells(chngRow, 5) <> "" Then
        Income = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range("C3", ws.Cells(chngRow, 3)))
        Expense = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range("D3", ws.Cells(chngRow, 4)))
        Total = Income + Expense
        ws.Cells(chngRow, 5) = Total
    End If
  Else
    MsgBox "Else is thrown."
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Application.EnableEvents = True 'so that future changes can be read
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your explanation.  What worksheet is the `Worksheet_Change` code in?

Comment: I haven't seen the complete code but I think you need `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` instead of `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` to cater to both sheets. This code will lie in `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: The worksheet where "Worksheet_Change" code is in .worksheets("OperationFund") but I even recently made a button to that sheet and not even a macro from that sheet trips the change.

Comment: afaik, your assumption is false. If you have a `worksheet_change()` event on a worksheet and anything makes a change to a range in that worksheet the `worksheet_change()` event will trip. This is why we have `Application.EnableEvents` so we can toggle that functionality off and avoid endless loops, which you have used here in your worksheet_change event code. If there was no worry of VBA triggering the event, those two lines would be superfluous. Perhaps something is happening causing a failure in your code AFTER you toggle `enableEvents` off which will stay off until you toggle it back on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to be pretentious to answer my own question, but my friend helped me find the solution, and maybe this will help others with a similar problem.

The key factor is that I'm using a button on UserForm to write data to the cell. It's not actually "changing" the cell when I write "Cells(#,#) = value". In my code, I needed to turn the Sub public and then

```
Call ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheetname").Worksheet_Change(Target.address)
```

This made everything work!
His example to help me: https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/767919-trigger-click-event-button-another-form